# How to make real-time AS3 Flash game?

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, real-time

So I have created flash game with Adobe Flash Professional codded by Action Script 3.0.

Game is fighting type 1 vs 1. I need to make It real time game for Facebook. For that is needed AppWarp?

I misunderstand how It works. I found example [here](https://github.com/shephertz/AppWarpAS3Library/tree/master/SpriteMoveDemo) but here is .fla file, I don't know how to test It and how to run It without .fla file?

Other question, why I need to register to [apphq.shephertz.com](https://apphq.shephertz.com/register/app42Login)? Here is function "Create app" but I misunderstand how to import my already created flash game here?

Or I don't need It at all If I'm creating real-time game for Facebook? Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at multi-user game servers like Smartfox and ElectroTank server.

Smartfox:
http://www.smartfoxserver.com/

Electrotank:
http://www.electrotank.com/es5.html

Comment: Thank you for answer, If you understand something I have asked one more similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391044/as3-how-to-set-up-players-for-real-time-game Maybe do you understand and can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding how [AppWarp](http://appwarp.shephertz.com) works. AppWarp is a **cloud solution** which allows you to exchange real-time data between your game clients. Using the AS3 SDK, you can connect to AppWarp cloud and create/join rooms and play with opponents. Unlike other solutions suggested by Plastic Sturgeon - you don't need to host or deploy your server and simply do AS3 client coding.

You need to "Create App" in AppHQ - because that will give you application keys that you put in your AS3 client code when using AppWarp. These keys are required so that your application's traffic can be segregated from other user's whose games are also running on AppWarp cloud server. So this app that you create in AppHQ represents the "server-side" of your app.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I got error when I'm trying to do this. Maybe you could help me? I've asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490889/how-to-successfully-integrate-appwarp-to-actionscript-3-code